# Strange search form behavior

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a strange behavior going on my gallery page. At the footer of the page I have simple simple search form which is supposed to show the results on searchmyway.php page. Instead it just takes me to the top of the gallery page without showing any errors. I have the same code on my other pages but the search form functions as it supposed to. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the page where the search works perfectly. The search box is on the bottom of the page. Try a word search for 'Colorado'.

[www.rajeevthomas.com](http://www.rajeevthomas.com/)

This is the page that is causing the problem. Please try the word 'Colorado' in the search box on the bottom of the page.

http://www.rajeevthomas.com/photos/

Here is the code I have in the footer

```
<div class="footinner">
<form name="seeker" id="seeker" action="searchmyway.php" method="get"><input type="text" name="q" id="search"/>
<input type="submit"  id="find" value="Search" />
<input type="hidden" name="form_id:search" value="1" />
</form>
</div><!--footinner-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your source code for both files, there is a difference in the forms.

*www.rajeevthomas.com* (working):

```
<form action="searchmyway.php" method="get">
```

*www.rajeevthomas.com/photos/* (not working):

```
<form name="seeker" id="seeker" action="searchmyway.php" method="get">
```

I am thinking that this may have something to do with the problem.

Try it without the `name` and `id`. Doesn't seem to be necessary.

Comment: Thank you Mark. Now both are the same code. I tried removing the 'name' and 'id' but it affects the form. Then it is searchable at all on any pages. But the behavior continues sadly.

Comment: @yathrakaaran Hmmm... I don't know. You are getting a 301:Redirect to /photos when you submit from that page. Could be something in `searchmyway.php` but I don't know - doesn't make much sense. If you don't have it already download `HttpFox` to track headers ... might help you troubleshooting

Comment: Mark... thank you for helping me with this. You pointed me in the right direction. I think this occurs because of some of my rules in .htaccess file.

Comment: @Mark...the behavior happened because my relative link in the form was appending to the link of the page. I changed it to an absolute link the problem went away. Thanks again for your time.